# Android XML Integer Array of Drawable Images referencing

Tags: java, android, arrays, xml

So I have a listview with a bunch of rows that when you click on one it opens up a new activity. This new activity displays some information and then an image below it. I've successfully gotten string information to display using a string array in xml. But I can't figure out how to do it using an integer array in xml with a bunch of @drawable links.

Is there a way to do it similar to how I have done it with the routedetail string array. Where I can use an intent.getExtra()

heres my mainactivity.java

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //fill list view with xml array of routes
    final String[] values =   getResources().getStringArray(R.array.routeList);

    //fills route detail text view with xml array info
    final String[] routeDetail= getResources().getStringArray(R.array.routeDetail);

    //fills route detail image view with xml array of images
    final TypedArray image = getResources().obtainTypedArray(R.array.routeImage);

    //custom adapter for list view
    ListAdapter routeAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, values);
    final ListView routeListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.routeListView);
    routeListView.setAdapter(routeAdapter);

    routeListView.setOnItemClickListener(
            new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    String route = values[position];

                    //for loop to increment through each route list item
                    int i;
                    for (i=0; i < values.length;i++)
                    {
                        if (route.equals(values[i]))
                        {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), RouteDetails.class);
                            intent.putExtra("route", routeDetail[i]);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
    );
}
}
```

Heres my route detail.java

This is the line that references my intent in mainactivity
routeDetailsView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("route"));

```
package com.example.zach.listview;

import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ScaleGestureDetector;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class RouteDetails extends AppCompatActivity {

Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
Float scale = 1f;
ScaleGestureDetector SGD;
ImageView routeImage;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_route_details);

    //TextView for route details
    final TextView routeDetailsView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.routeDetailsView);
    routeDetailsView.setText(getIntent().getExtras().getString("route"));

    //ImageView for route details
    routeImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.routeImage);
    //routeImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.birdsboroareamap);


    SGD = new ScaleGestureDetector(this, new ScaleListener());
}
//listener for pinch zoom
private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener{
    @Override
     public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
        scale = scale * detector.getScaleFactor();
        scale = Math.max(0.1f, Math.min(scale, 5f));
        matrix.setScale(scale, scale);
        routeImage.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    SGD.onTouchEvent(event);
    return true;
}
}
```

and heres my routelistviewitems xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

<string-array name="routeList">
    <item>Information</item>
    <item>Crag Map</item>
    <item>Main Wall</item>
    <item>1. Shark Bait - 5.9</item>
    <item>2. Rain Check - 5.8</item>
    <item>3. Rain Check Direct - 5.8</item>
    <item>4. Arocknophobia - 5.7</item>
    <item>5. Balls Deep - 5.9+</item>
    <item>6. Jingle Bells - 5.9</item>
    <item>7. Itching to Climb - 5.8</item>
    <item>8. Hog Nose 5.10+</item>
    <item>9. Slab Dance - 5.10</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="routeDetail">
    <item>Information</item>
    <item>Crag Map</item>
    <item>Overview of the Main Wall Climbing Area</item>
    <item>1. Shark Bait - 5.9</item>
    <item>2. Rain Check - 5.8</item>
    <item>3. Rain Check Direct - 5.8</item>
    <item>4. Arocknophobia - 5.7</item>
    <item>5. Balls Deep - 5.9+</item>
    <item>6. Jingle Bells - 5.9</item>
    <item>7. Itching to Climb - 5.8</item>
    <item>8. Hog Nose 5.10+</item>
    <item>9. Slab Dance - 5.10</item>
</string-array>

<integer-array name="routeImage">

    <item>@drawable/birdsboroareamap</item>

</integer-array>

</resources>
```

Thank you for any help!
Still looking for any help!

Comment: `integer-array` should be lowercase

Comment: thanks I noticed that. any input on my question?